# Html DropDownListFor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a problem with my `DropDownListFor`, I want a `DropDownlist` with 1,2,3,4,5 etc. on my View.

In my model class:

```
public class PageModel 
{
   [DisplayName("Quantity")]
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a `Quantity` class

```
 public class Quantity
    {
        public int Selection { get; set; }
    }
```

A HtmlList class

```
public static class HtmlLists
    {
       public static IEnumerable<Quantity> Selections = new List<Quantity> { 
            new Quantity {
                Selection = 1
            },
            new Quantity {
                Selection = 2
            }
        };
```

On my View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity):
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Quantity, new SelectList(HtmlList.Selections, "Selection"))
```

It is giving me an error at `HtmlList.Selections`:

> The name 'HtmlList' does not exists in the current context

**EDIT:**

My error issue is fixed with @using YourNameSpaceofStaticClass

But now i have the folliwing problem:

Instead of showing me the selection 1 and 2 in the dropdownlist he is showing me:

> ModelNamespace.Quantity 
>   ModelNamespace.Quantity

I think this is beacause my List is empty..

Namespace of my Quantity class:

```
namespace ModelNamespace
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the namespace for the static class in your view.

```
@using RandomProject.Helpers;
```

and one suggestion, instead of creating static class, you can create a property in your viewmodel.

```
public class yourViewModel
{
      public IEnumerable<Quantity> Selections {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: `@using YourNameSpaceofStaticClass` should suffice :)

Comment: When i create the property in my ViewModel, how can i add the values what needs to be in my dropdownlist like 1 and 2 etc. because now i adds them in my Htmllist class